# Memory Optimization With UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a custom subclass of UIView who has been allocated. Every time I invoke the class, i need to realloc it's subviews like this:

```
- (void)invoke{
    [[self subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in self.list){
        MySubview *subView = [[MySubview alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [self addSubview:subView];
    }
}
```

So the result is that every time I invoke it, the memory increases by around 4MB.
Then how can I fix it and optimize my memory?

Comment: check all subviews are removed before loop

Comment: What is `MySubview`? What does it do / contain?

Comment: you can save all subView in array and then remove from superview for all

Comment: MySubview is also a custom subclass of UIView

Answer (score 1):

`[someView removeFromSuperView]` is not the same as `someView = nil;`

you'll have to ensure that each view you are attempting to eradicate is set to nil. Otherwise they will hang around until ARC thinks it's time to expunge them (probably when the superview is destroyed) or you call `release` on them (for non ARC)

Comment: Then how can I remove all the subviews of a view and set them to nil?

Comment: typically the parent view sets it's subviews to nil.